# Does "drive home" have a Literal meaning (like going home but by car)?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, idioms

[In dictionary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/drive%20home), "**drive home**" has 2 meanings

> 1. carry out or perform
>
> “The boxer drove home a solid left”
>
> 2. make clear by special emphasis and try to convince somebody of something
>
> “drive home a point or an argument”
>
> “I'm trying to drive home these basic ideas”

My question is:

Does "**drive home**" have a literal meaning?

Does it also mean "**go home by car**"? Ex: *I want to drive home*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "drive home" is an established expression, but the words can also be taken literally and you can indeed say that you drove home.

"I drove home after a productive day at work."

This type of expression is called an *idiom*.

There are quite a few of these and they are even used in a class of wordplay jokes because of the "double meaning".

Answer (score 0):

yes, "drive home" is perfectly correct in the car sense and also the only time I can think of when you don't use the preposition "to".
You can "drive home" but you must  "drive TO work/school/a friend's house"